# Replace multiple characters in string in one line of code in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, string, replace

Using VB.NET I'd like to be able to replace a range of characters in a string in a single line of code.

I.e., something like:

```
Dim charsToReplace as string = "acegi"
Dim stringToBeReplaced as string = "abcdefghijklmnop"

charsToReplace.ToArray().ForEach(Function (c) stringTobeReplaced = stringTobeReplaced.Replace(c, ""))
```

However, this doesn't work.

The following does work, however I don't want the string to be a class level variable:

```
 Sub Main()
    Dim toReplace As String = "acegikmoq"

    Console.WriteLine(mainString)
    Dim chars As List(Of Char) = toReplace.ToList()
    chars.ForEach(AddressOf replaceVal)

    Console.WriteLine(mainString)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Dim mainString As String = "this is my string that has values in it that I am going to quickly replace all of..."

Sub replaceVal(ByVal c As Char)
    mainString = mainString.Replace(c, "")
End Sub
```

Can this be done?

Comment: This is a case of "should have asked the exact question instead of rephrasing it". To elaborate, I actually have a string which is basically a series of words, separated by spaces. I have an array of words that I want to strip out of the string, hence why I thought the foreach would be possible/useful. When the (different) question is asked in this way, Regex is not suitable. so basically:
dim words() as string = ("the", "brown", "lazy")
dim sentence as string = "the quick brown fox jumps"
 results="quick fox jumps"
my hope was for words.ForEach(Function (w) sentence.Replace(w, "")

Answer (score 28):

If I read this correctly, you're trying to strip a list of characters from a string. This is a good fit for a RegEx.

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace("abcdefghijklmnop", "[acegi]", string.Empty))
```

(you'll need to import System.Text.RegularExpressions)

Comment: what about the performance of that method, if used very often?

Comment: @serhio : Regex is in fact, made for string manipulation. Whatever else you use to handle string, regex do it way much faster and use less ressources.

Comment: @SimonDugré  as shown in my answer (which was earlier than your comment)  it is the other way around.   Regex is way much slower.

Answer (score 8):

The RegEx approach is the best suited, but what I really need to say is:

Please, for the love of maintenance developers, don't get hung-up on getting this down to 1 line of code.  One method call is your real goal, if you end up just piling a bunch of calls into 1 line to say it's one-line then you're shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: It's not really my main goal to get it to one line for development purposes, more for "got a bee in my bonnet because it didn't work how I thought it should, and want to figure out how to do it" purposes... :)

Comment: +1 for the maintenance developers - been there, done that, had that headache! =)

Answer (score 7):

I didn't believe Bittercode as he said that LINQ would outperform regex.
So I did a little test just to be sure.

Three examples of how to do this:

```
Dim _invalidChars As Char() = New Char() {"j"c, "a"c, "n"c}
Dim _textToStrip As String = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

Private Sub btnStripInvalidCharsLINQ_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStripInvalidCharsLINQ.Click
    Dim stripped As String = String.Empty
    Dim sw As Stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew
    For i As Integer = 0 To 10000
        stripped = _textToStrip.Where(Function(c As Char) Not _invalidChars.Contains(c)).ToArray
    Next
   sw.Stop()

    lblStripInvalidCharsLINQ.Text = _stripped & " - in " & sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds & " ms"
End Sub

Private Sub btnStripInvalidCharsFOR_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStripInvalidCharsFOR.Click
    Dim stripped As String = String.Empty
    Dim sw As Stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew
    stripped = _textToStrip
    For i As Integer = 0 To 10000
        For Each c As Char In _invalidChars
            stripped = stripped.Replace(c, "")
        Next
    Next
    sw.Stop()

    lblStipInvalidcharsFor.Text = stripped & " - in " & sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds & " ms"
End Sub

Private Sub btnStripInvalidCharsREGEX_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStripInvalidCharsREGEX.Click
    Dim stripped As String = String.Empty
    Dim sw As Stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew
    For i As Integer = 0 To 10000
        stripped = Regex.Replace(_textToStrip, "[" & New String(_invalidChars) & "]", String.Empty)
    Next
    sw.Stop()

    lblStripInvalidCharsRegex.Text = stripped & " - in " & sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds & " ms"
End Sub
```

The results:

[image: Performance result]

So,  the for loop with string.replace outperformes all the other methods.

Because of this I would make an extension function to the string object.

```
Module StringExtensions
<Extension()> _
Public Function ReplaceAll(ByVal InputValue As String, ByVal chars As Char(), replaceWith As Char) As String
    Dim ret As String = InputValue
    For Each c As Char In chars
        ret = ret.Replace(c, replaceWith)
    Next
    Return ret
End Function
```

Then you could use this function nice and readably in one line:

```
_textToStrip.ReplaceAll(_invalidChars, CChar(String.Empty))
```

EDIT (10 years later):

I once again needed this to be as fast as possible.
I wrote a real performance test this time (benchmarkdotnet).
I used  net6.0.

Code available in github: https://github.com/j-dc/stackoverflow_1332454

```
    //[SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.Net462, baseline: true)]
    //[SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.Net48)]
    [SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.Net60)]
    [RPlotExporter]
    public class RemoveChars {
        private static readonly char[] _invalidChars = new[] { 'j', 'a', 'n' };
        private static readonly string _textToStrip = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

        private static readonly HashSet<char> _invalidHash = new(new[] { 'j', 'a', 'n' });


        [Benchmark]
        public string Linq() {
            return new string(_textToStrip.Where(x => !_invalidChars.Contains(x)).ToArray());
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public string ForEach() {
            string ret = _textToStrip;
            foreach(char c in _invalidChars) {
                ret = ret.Replace(Convert.ToString(c), "");
            }
            return ret;
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public string Regexer() {
            return Regex.Replace(_textToStrip, $"[{new string(_invalidChars) }]", string.Empty);
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public string Hasher() {
            return new string(_textToStrip.Where(x => _invalidHash.Contains(x)).ToArray());
        }

        [Benchmark]

        public string Splitting() {
            return string.Join(string.Empty, _textToStrip.Split(_invalidChars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public string Aggregate() {
            return _invalidChars.Aggregate(_textToStrip, (c1, c2) => c1.Replace(Convert.ToString(c2), ""));
        }


    }


}
```

Results:

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LinqToArray | 635.2 ns | 12.20 ns | 11.42 ns |
| ForEach | 119.0 ns | 1.58 ns | 1.40 ns |
| Regexer | 392.0 ns | 7.38 ns | 8.50 ns |
| Hasher | 402.0 ns | 6.04 ns | 5.65 ns |
| ***Splitting*** | ***109.8 ns*** | 1.84 ns | 1.72 ns |
| Aggregate | 136.6 ns | 2.62 ns | 2.45 ns |

Comment: The Linq method involves a linear lookup in the array of invalid chars.  What happens if it's a `HashSet(Of Char)` instead?

Comment: @craig using a hashset of char, made the worst method a little bit less worse (see my edit).  The best turned out to be this splitting method.

Answer (score 1):

The String class has a replace method to do this. You can use it this way:

```
YourString = YourString.Replace("OldValue", "NewValue")
```

Comment: I may not have been completely clear, but I want to replace every instance of every character in the string. i.e. 
chars = "ace"
longString = "abcdeabcdeabcde"

result = "bdbdbd"

replace is not able to do this.

Comment: You can actually use Replace more than once on the same statement :

myDate2 = Date.Now.ToString("s").Replace(":", "-").Replace("T", " ")

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Jon Galloway's approach, a regular expression is the appropriate method, and future developers will thank you for it :) - though it's not a difficult problem to solve with Linq as well.  Here's some (untested) C# code to do that:

```
string stringToBeReplaced = "abcdefghijklmnop";
string charsToReplace = "acegi";
stringToBeReplaced = new String(stringToBeReplaced.Where(c => !charsToReplace.Any(rc => c == rc)).ToArray());
```

I suspect this code will probably perform slightly better then the regex equivalent, if performance is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

What is the best way to repeat the line statement if you really want to use that code:

```
Sub Main() 

    Dim myString As String = Nothing
    Dim finalString As String = Nothing
    Console.Write("Please enter a string: ") 'your free to put anything
    myString = Console.ReadLine()
    finalString = myString.Replace("0", "")
    myString = finalString
    finalString = myString.Replace("1", "")
    myString = finalString
    finalString = myString.Replace("2", "")
    myString = finalString
    finalString = myString.Replace("3", "")
    myString = finalString
    finalString = myString.Replace("4", "")
    myString = finalString
    finalString = myString.Replace("5", "")
    myString = finalString
    finalString = myString.Replace("6", "")
    myString = finalString
    finalString = myString.Replace("7", "")
    myString = finalString
    finalString = myString.Replace("8", "")
    myString = finalString
    finalString = myString.Replace("9", "")
    Console.WriteLine(finalString)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

For example: if you typed: `012ALP456HA90BET678` the output would be: `ALPHABET`.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please have a look at the edits I made to your question so you know how to better ask questions in future.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function SuperReplace(ByRef field As String, ByVal ReplaceString As String) As String
  ' Size this as big as you need... it is zero-based by default'
  Dim ReplaceArray(4) As String

  'Fill each element with the character you need to replace'

  ReplaceArray(0) = "WARD NUMBER "
  ReplaceArray(1) = "WN "
  ReplaceArray(2) = "WARD NO "
  ReplaceArray(3) = "WARD-"
  ReplaceArray(4) = "WARD "

  Dim i As Integer
  For i = LBound(ReplaceArray) To UBound(ReplaceArray)
    field = Replace(field, ReplaceArray(i), ReplaceString)
    Next i
  SuperReplace = field
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub cmdTest_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdTest.Click
    Dim s As String = "México Juárez índice recúrso dirección"
    Dim arr() As String = {"á", "é", "í", "ó", "ú", "Ñ", "ñ"}
    Dim rep() As String = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "N", "n"}
    Dim i As Integer = Nothing

    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        s = Replace(s, arr(i), rep(i))
    Next

    MsgBox(s)

End Sub
```

Comment: BOTH Arrays have to grow parallel to each other, you can replace simple characters and/or strings BUT the number of elements inside each array have to be the same. Hope this is clear, also hope this is useful...