# Working with strings and replace

Tags: c#, asp.net

what can I use to replace the string if its in the following format

```
   I' have a "car" that runs very well
```

So basically i have a search function

and if they just type `'` it wasnt finding it so i did

```
mySearchWord.Replace("'", "''")
```

and then it found it but now what if there is an `'` and `"` in the same sentence or word, how can i check for both in mySearchWord ?

because for both cases i would do something like

```
    mySearchWord.Replace("'", "''") 

mySearchWord.Replace("\"", "\"") //have no idea about this one
```

or something like that, is there a way to do it at once?

I think someone below is pointing me in the right direction, i just need to be able to pass apostrophes or quotation marks to my search but it was throwing an error maube because when passed, just as in sql, you would need to escape a quotation or apostrophe

Comment: Not sure I follow, so you want ' => '' (two single ticks), but you want " => "?  What's the point of the latter?  Or am I misreading?

Comment: Can you clarify -- I've read this 3 times and I'm not sure of your objective.

Comment: Maybe if you showed us what the literal response string you want for that example looks like?

Comment: I'd probably use the StringBuilder or Regex class http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321331/replace-multiple-string-elements-in-c/1321343#1321343 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332454/replace-multiple-characters-in-string-in-one-line-of-code-in-vb-net/1332650#1332650

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This actually replaces both at once:

```
string text = "I' have a \"car\" that runs very well";
string pattern = "['\"]";
var result = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, m => (m.Value == "'") ? "''" : "\"\"");
```

I should explain.

This is using a method called Regular Expressions. The `pattern` variable is the regular expression *pattern* which is used to match things in the string `text`. In this case the pattern states that it should match all `'` and `"` characters in the text. The pattern `[abc]` would match all `a`, `b` and `c` characters.

Regular Expressions seem complex at first, but is very powerful.

You find the `Regex` class in the `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace.

Here is the documentation for it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c75he57e(v=VS.100).aspx

The code `m => (m.Value == "'") ? "''" : "\"\""` is a Lambda expression, which is a short hand to the Delegate `MatchEvaluator` ([docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator.aspx)).

Answer (score 2):

```
mySearchWord.Replace("''", "[{just_to_replace}]").Replace("'", "''").Replace("[{just_to_replace}]", "''");
```

cool, ain't it.

Comment: +1 faster than me, but I will like to say that you are not doing it at once ;) just all in one line...

Comment: Sadly `string`s are immutable! :-) `mySearchWord = ...`